# How to control Thread because it work incorrect?

Tags: c#, multithreading

My problem is:

I want to run through all `ListStudent`; it has five rows.

I am using `for()` to loop through all element in `ListStudent` and start thread corresponding.

It must run `StartProcess(dtStudent.Rows[0].ToString(), 1);` to ``StartProcess(dtStudent.Rows[5].ToString(), 1);`

But when I tried to debug, at rows `while (run_process[idxThread].bwIsRun == true)` - variable `idxThread` always is 5.

And I want it only run first thread because I will input to a program. After, when I click again `btnProcess` it will continue to next `dtStudent.Rows`.

Have any method to do this? Thanks..

I don't have to know an issue with my code.

This all my code to do this:

```
LThread[] run_process =new LThread[0];
int num_process = 0;
public void btnProcess()
{
    DataTable dtStudent = mysql_db.ExcelLoad("ListStudent");
    int total_row_student = dtStudent.Rows.Count;        // 5 rows
    if (num_process != total_row_student)
    {
        run_process = new LThread[total_row_student];

        for (int idx = 0; idx < total_row_student; idx++)
        {
            run_process[idx] = new LThread();
            run_process[idx].StartedEvent += new LThread.startDelegate(delegate (string arg)
            {
                StartProcess(dtStudent.Rows[idx - 1]["number"].ToString(), idx - 1);
            });
        }
    }
    num_process = total_row_student;
    if (num_process == 0)
        return;
    flag = true;
    Start_all_thread();
}

private void Start_all_thread()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < run_process.Length; i++)
        if (run_process[i] != null)
            run_process[i].Start();
}
private void Stop_all_thread()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < run_process.Length; i++)
        if (run_process[i] != null)
            run_process[i].Stop();
}

private void StartProcess(string output, int idxThread)
{
    while (run_process[idxThread].bwIsRun == true)
    {
        if (flag == false)
            continue;

        // some code at here
        Stop_all_thread();
    }
}
```

And class LThread.cs is define:

```
public class LThread2
{
    public delegate void startDelegate(string ID);
    public event startDelegate StartedEvent;
    public Boolean bwIsRun;
    MicroTimer microTimer = new MicroTimer();
    public LThread2()
    {
        microTimer.MicroTimerElapsed +=
            new MicroTimer.MicroTimerElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);

        microTimer.Interval = 2000; 
    }
    private static int RandNumber(int Low, int High)
    {
        Random rndNum = new Random(int.Parse(Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 8), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber));

        int rnd = rndNum.Next(Low, High);

        return rnd;
    }
    public void Start()
    {
        try
        {
            bwIsRun = true;
            microTimer.Enabled = true;
        }
        catch { }
    }
    public void Stop()
    {
        try
        {
            bwIsRun = false;
            microTimer.Enabled = false;
        }
        catch { }
    }
    private void OnTimedEvent(object sender,MicroTimerEventArgs timerEventArgs)
    {
        StartedEvent(RandNumber(100, 10000).ToString());
    }
}
/// <summary>
/// Class emulates long process which runs in worker thread
/// and makes synchronous user UI operations.
/// </summary>
public class LThread : BackgroundWorker
{
    #region Members
    public delegate void startDelegate(string ID);
    public event startDelegate StartedEvent;
    private static int RandNumber(int Low, int High)
    {
        Random rndNum = new Random(int.Parse(Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 8), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber));

        int rnd = rndNum.Next(Low, High);

        return rnd;
    }
    protected override void OnDoWork(DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {

        StartedEvent(RandNumber(100,10000).ToString()); //put whatever parameter suits you or nothing
        base.OnDoWork(e);
        e.Result = e.Argument;
    }
    BackgroundWorker bwThread;
    // Main thread sets this event to stop worker thread:
    public Boolean bwIsRun;
    int m_time_delay = 10000;
    Delegate m_form_method_run;
    Delegate m_form_method_stop;
    Form m_type_form;
    #endregion

    #region Functions

    public void Start()
    {
        try
        {
            bwIsRun = true;
            this.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
        catch { }
    }
    public void Stop()
    {
        try
        {
            bwIsRun = false;
        }
        catch { }
    }
    private void StartToListen(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(m_time_delay);
            if (bwIsRun == true)
            {
                m_type_form.Invoke(m_form_method_run);                    
            }
            else
            {
                BackgroundWorker bwAsync = sender as BackgroundWorker;
                if (bwAsync.CancellationPending)
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                    return;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: if you are debugging, you can only see 1 thread at a time.

Comment: In real working, it also runs with `idx=5`. I have 5 rows in DataTable, but it always runs thread with final rows.

Comment: `idx` start from 0 but in `StartProcess` Rows index will be negative because you use `idx-1`

Comment: If I don't using `idx-1` because I only have max is 5, but I don't know this value is 6. and throw an exception like over index in an array.

Comment: Please don't do `Random rndNum = new Random(int.Parse(Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 8), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber))` - just make `rndNum` a static field and initialize it with `new Random()`. This will ensure a good random stream without all of the `Guid` higgery pokery.

Comment: Thanks, @Enigmativity. Error seem at line: `StartedEvent(RandNumber(100, 10000).ToString());`. Do you have any suggest to fix my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You issue is probably in the `for (int idx = 0; idx < total_row_student; idx++)` for-loop. You're starting threads that will start long after the loop is finished so the variable `idx` is already at `5` before any of the threads actually start.

Try changing the code to this to fix:

```
for (int idx = 0; idx < total_row_student; idx++)
{
    int local_idx = idx;
    run_process[idx] = new LThread();
    run_process[idx].StartedEvent += new LThread.startDelegate(delegate (string arg)
    {
        StartProcess(dtStudent.Rows[local_idx - 1]["number"].ToString(), local_idx - 1);
    });
}
```